# phpMyAdminのポートフォワードがうまくいかない

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdminのポートフォワードがうまくいかない

データベースmysqlサーバ(192.168.2.42)に対して別マシン(192.168.2.44)から接続をおこなおうとしております。
そこでポートフォワードの設定をおこないました。

```
ssh -f -N -C -L 10000:127.0.0.1:3306 root@192.168.2.44 -p 22
```

ここで別マシンのphpMyAdminにアクセスをして、DBサーバのmysqlのDBスキーマも確認できました。

ただし、ポートフォワードの設定のプロセスをkillしても依然として、DBサーバへの接続ができております。

phpMyAdmin展開後の`config.inc.php`の記述内容は下記となっております。

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.2.42';

$cfg['Server'][$i]['port'] = '10000';
```

これはただ、mysqlサーバの3306デフォルトポートに接続しにいってしまっているということでしょうか。

どこを見直せばいいかご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: MySQL が 192.168.2.44 で phpMyAdmin が 192.168.2.42 ですか？
ssh コマンドは 192.168.2.42 で実行しているのですよね？

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
すいません、間違えました。
おっしゃるとおり、MySQL が 192.168.2.44 で phpMyAdmin が 192.168.2.42 です。

Comment: @lackwiki 質問の内容に誤りがあるのであればコメントではなく質問を編集して訂正してください

Answer (score 1):

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.2.42';
>      $cfg['Server'][$i]['port'] = '10000';

phpMyAdminの設定は良くわからないのですが、後者が`Servers`ではなく`Server`になっているためにデフォルトポートの3306が使用されていて、SSHとは無関係に192.168.2.42:3306に接続されているのではないでしょうか。

それ以前の部分からいろいろおかしいので、一から設計を見直すことをお勧めします。

> データベースmysqlサーバ(192.168.2.42)に対して別マシン(192.168.2.44)から接続をおこなおうとしております。
>   そこでポートフォワードの設定をおこないました。
>
> ```
> ssh -f -N -C -L 10000:127.0.0.1:3306 root@192.168.2.44 -p 22
> ```

このsshの接続では、MySQLサーバ側の127.0.0.1:10000がphpMyAdminマシン側の127.0.0.1:3306に転送されています。(-gが指定されていないので、192.168.2.42:10000は開いていません)

一方、phpMyAdminの設定では、192.168.2.42:10000に接続しようという意図だと見受けられます。この場合、192.168.2.44→192.168.2.42:10000はSSHトンネルを通りません。

```
 192.168.2.42(MySQL)             192.168.2.44(phpMyAdmin)
---------------------  (SSH)     --------------------
|                    |----------->|
|    127.0.0.1:10000-+============+-->127.0.0.1:3306
|                    |----------->|
|                    |            |
|(192.168.2.42:10000)|<- ---------|(phpMyAdmin)
  ※今の設定では開いてない
```

そもそもMySQL over SSHが本当にやりたいことでしょうか。ネットワークが信頼できない場合であればMySQLはネイティブでSSL接続をサポートしていますのでこちらを検討すべきです。

Comment: @suzukisさん

ご指摘ありがとうございます。
MySQL が 192.168.2.44 で phpMyAdmin が 192.168.2.42です。

sshコマンドはphpMyAdminサーバ(192.168.2.42)の方でおこないました。
その上でServer→Serversに変更しました。

ssh -f -N -g -C -L 10000:127.0.0.1:3306 root@192.168.2.44 -p 22

しかし、ログインができません。
変更したServersのポート番号は10000だとログインができません。
3306に変更するとログイン可能です。

この状態でも設定に誤認識がありますでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @lackwiki 質問へのコメントにも書きましたが、質問の内容に誤りがあったのであれば、コメントに書くのではなく質問を編集して訂正してください。また、新たに試したことがあるのであれば、同じく質問を編集して追記してください。追記部分は追記である事がはっきり区別出来るほうがよいです。